# SDL text or additional images not loading

Tags: 2d, sdl, c, side-scroller

I've got a basic side scroller that allows the user to run and jump around. I've used various tutorials to get this far, but I can't seem to get any text to render, no matter what method. I also can't get any images to render outside of my draw() function which is rendered at run time, which I think is my problem. (Is it possible to recall the function again to load another image?)

I can't just give a line of code to show the issue since the whole program is interwoven together:

http://pastebin.com/d1CNiVf5

I'm not asking for someone to go through the code and fix everything, just if you could point me in the right direction, or at least know what is causing the problem that would be great!

(Sorry about having all the code in one file, I'm bad a modularising it and kept on getting errors early on in the project because of it. So for learning purposes it's going to be in one file for now).

Edit: At the moment the priority is to get projectiles working. I've tried SDL_UpdateRect and similar but nothing has helped so far.

Edit #2:
SO I've created a new function and have called it on top of the map, like it should do. But now I get a strange output:
http://youtu.be/8piWyjfDgbI

Comment: Just a quick comment; you shouldn't limit your frame rate. Make movement according to delta time ( time since last frame )

Also; on what line do you try to draw the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SDL_FillRect(screen , &bullet[i].b , 0xFFFF66);
```

This will fill your `screen` surface in the SDL_Rect `&bullet[i].b`

Then later in the same frame, you use `drawImage`
To draw the map over the entire size of `screen`, covering up the projectiles you filled it up with.

I suggest you add a separate SDL_Surface* for your projectile and draw them in your `draw()` function.

Comment: How would I get draw() to only call the projectile when space is pressed? Otherwise if I put a call in draw() it'll render the bullet when the program starts.

Comment: There's several possibilities. My suggestion is to add all active projectiles to a std::vector, then you would just draw the entire vector in `draw()`

A quicker option would be to add a `bool` to your projectile `struct` that specifies whether or not it should be drawn.

Comment: I'm using pure C, so i can't use the std::vector. As for that bool, it gave me an idea but it crashes the program now. What I did:
New function drawBullet():
http://pastebin.com/ZGhEe3c8
A bool called fireBullet. Replaced the SDLK_SPACE code by setting fireBullet = true;
Calling drawBullet() in draw().

Comment: @AlexKontos update your main post instead, it's easier to read

Comment: I saw what was wrong, I was calling drawBullet() in drawBullet() by accident! But now I get this REALLY weird sort of output:
http://youtu.be/8piWyjfDgbI

(Main post has been updated too)

Comment: @AlexKontos is the problem that the projectile gets drawn several times? If so, all you need to do is clear the surface you are blitting the projectile to

Comment: The main issue is that it fires the projectiles the moment it loads, but then it also seems to randomly accept the spacebar input to fire. So every time I hit spacebar, it won't fire anything from the sprite and if it does, nowhere near the sprite. Only when it loads does it fire perfectly.